# How to push to a remote SVN repository ... that I am tracking

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a local branch that I created via

```
git branch --track <localFeatureBranch> <remoteSVNBranch>
```

I've checked out the branch locally and when I pull, I can see that Git automatically knows where to pull from

```
$ git pull
From .
* remote-tracking branch remoteSVNBranch     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Now that I've made several changes and committed them to the local branch - I would like to push them up to the remote repository. When I do the obvious:

```
$ git status
# On branch localFeatureBranch
# Your branch is ahead of 'remoteSVNBranch' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

And then try to push

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

It thinks we're all up-to-date ... but we're not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push` will push into a git repository, not the svn one. Your choice is `git svn dcommit` (see `git svn help` or google it for more details.)

Comment: That was it! Thanks Alex. I found some good supporting details here: http://progit.org/book/ch8-1.html